# How do I fill a scene with light by using real-time lights in Unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, lighting, unity-urp

This is my scene:

[image: Scene with a cube and a spotlight]

Components of this scene:

1. Cube
2. Spotlight

This project is under URP and I am building it for android. In this scene, I want more indirect lighting so that the objects/materials nearby are at least partly visible and to get rid of the strong circular boundary of the spot light on the floor.

As a comment suggests, using Indirect Lighting might be complex, especially for mobile, so what can I do? I tried increasing the spot angle but it did not look right.

Any alternatives would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can I just confirm what you're using the term "indirect light" to mean here? Usually in game rendering this refers to simulating the bouncing of light off of one surface to illuminate another - something that can be fairly expensive/complex to compute or approximate, particularly on mobile - and it doesn't look like this scene would benefit much from such extra complexity. So I'm wondering if you're meaning it in a different sense, like "light shining farther from the center of the spotlight" or adding more ambient/fill light to support the background regions. Those would be much cheaper.

Comment: @DMGregory "Lights shining farther from the centre of the spotlight" I assume, 
 would simply mean increasing the spot angle and that does not work right. And ambient light would make the scene brighter, but it might not help in getting rid of the circular boundary of the light

Comment: It sounds to me like you might just want to add another light somewhere in the scene, like a soft directional light to add some definition in the shadowed regions and keep the area outside the spotlight from becoming completely black. But if I'm misunderstanding you then it might help to edit your question to describe in more detail what you want to see, or mock up an example in a photo editing program to make sure we're clearly understanding the target look you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the [ambient lighting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-ambient-light.html) of the scene from the [Lighting Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html) in the Unity Editor. Ambient lighting is present throughout the scene and doesn't come from a specific light source; it's an inexpensive way to roughly simulate indirect lighting and ensure that all parts of a scene have a certain minimum level of brightness.

The exact steps to change the settings will vary depending on your Unity version, but here's how you do it in Unity 2020.3.x:

1. Open the Lighting window at Window > Rendering > Lighting
2. Select the "Environment" tab
3. Under the "Environment Lighting" section, choose your lighting source (Skybox, Gradient, or Color). "Color" is the easiest to work with but least realistic of the three options. Then adjust the settings for your selected lighting source.